# Quarkus and Smallrye JWT is not generating the token when running in native mode

Tags: kotlin, jwt, quarkus, smallrye, quarkus-native

I created a small project using Quarkus, Smallrye JWT, and Kotlin where a JWT token is generated. The token generation works fine when I'm running the app in JVM. However, **when I build the application into native and I run the application, the token is not generated anymore**.

Here are the steps that I took:

### Setting Up

#### Private and Public Keys Generation

```bash
openssl genrsa -out PrivateKey.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in PrivateKey.pem -outform PEM -pubout -out PublicKey.pem
```

Then I moved the keys to the `resources/META-INF/keys` folder.

#### Updated the application.yml

```yaml
smallrye:
  jwt:
    sign:
      key:
        location: "META-INF/keys/PrivateKey.pem"
    encrypt:
      key:
        location: "META-INF/keys/PublicKey.pem"
    verify:
      key:
        location: "META-INF/keys/PublicKey.pem"
```

### The Code

#### TokenService

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
class TokenService {

    fun generateToken(): String {
        val now = Instant.now()
        return Jwt.claims()
            .subject(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .upn("johndoe@example.com")
            .groups(setOf("SOME ROLE"))
            .issuer("A Issuer")
            .issuedAt(now)
            .expiresIn(Duration.ofHours(1))
            .expiresAt(now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS))
            .claim(Claims.email, "johndoe@example.com")
            .claim(Claims.given_name, "John")
            .claim(Claims.family_name, "Doe")
            .claim(Claims.full_name, "John Doe")
            .claim("some_custom_claim", "a value")
            .sign()
    }
}
```

#### JwtController

```kotlin
@Path("/generate-token")
class JwtController(private val tokenService: TokenService) {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun generateToken(): Response {
        val token = tokenService.generateToken()
        return Response.ok(TokenResponse(token)).build()
    }
}

data class TokenResponse(
    @field:JsonProperty("token")
    val token: String
)
```

### Building and Running

#### JVM

- Java 17.0.8
- Kotlin 1.9

```
openjdk version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.8+7 (build 17.0.8+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.8+7 (build 17.0.8+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```bash
quarkus build
java -jar ./build/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar
```

##### Request

```bash
curl --request POST --url http://localhost:8080/generate-token
```

##### Response (200 OK)

```json
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIzOGYwOTc1YS0zNjk1LTQxMDYtODUwNC1kZmZlYTk4ZGU5NWEiLCJ1cG4iOiJqb2huZG9lQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiZ3JvdXBzIjpbIlNPTUUgUk9MRSJdLCJpc3MiOiJBIElzc3VlciIsImlhdCI6MTY5MzIyMjA2NiwiZXhwIjoxNjkzMjI1NjY2LCJlbWFpbCI6ImpvaG5kb2VAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJnaXZlbl9uYW1lIjoiSm9obiIsImZhbWlseV9uYW1lIjoiRG9lIiwiZnVsbF9uYW1lIjoiSm9obiBEb2UiLCJzb21lX2N1c3RvbV9jbGFpbSI6ImEgdmFsdWUiLCJqdGkiOiJkOTE0ZmZmMy1mOGIzLTRlOTYtOGIzZC0zZTE5NjJlODg5YjgifQ.TBUy4RE82KcNop-Wfhbbml8vnZbO8zuY0DgnW9zIcfXYOBl60XubAMFspEzG90nV_au7IYiSvXIZW4AJV8XJhU56c9jC9LRB4c_z0TLfFnBAmxjNyBQ-3D8T2W3RwENnK9lwsMq789T4SuUzlNB8ouxDKO9x5UmDuKqym_SuH3z5PXDrfHqWbaMoiYK7v8ftKuK2HtuYlAokVO7dvFh1vRIUYoRGy1VmJSfk8QIRqXRGm5rWE9IkJFw5UDzcAF6L8WAWP4cYBeGzE49Xy3lG3J6MsY_FHN8ehUaa_ItKs-dANx-yW0oWJcmdS3kPjjN6kkuKGUTbcCsvxF5-IXdPHw"
}
```

#### Native Mode

```bash
sdk use java 23.r17-mandrel
quarkus build --native
```

```bash
./build/jwt-native-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner
```

##### Request

```bash
curl --request POST --url http://localhost:8080/generate-token
```

##### Response (200 OK)

```json
{}
```

As you can see, the token is generated fine when the application is running under JVM, but when running in native mode, everything looks fine, but the token is not generated. No error is shown in the logs.

The sample project is here: https://github.com/rgiaviti/bug-quarkus-jwt-generate-native-mode

Comment: Looks like a problem with code elemination/reflection. Could you add `@RegisterForReflection` on `class TokenResponse`?

Comment: In [this guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jwt#configuring-the-smallrye-jwt-extension-security-information) there additional information about how to include resources (e.g. publicKey.pem) to navtive image. Did you try it?

Comment: @zforgo, yes, I added this property: `quarkus.native.resources.includes=META-INF/keys/PublicKey.pem` in `application;yml`, but not worked. It worked with `@RegisterForReflection` without adding this property.